# JavaScript .children HTML collection length issues when looping

Tags: javascript, loops, xmlhttprequest, children

I'm attempting to loop through an HTMLCollection produced from JavaScript's `.children` property using the following code:

```
var articles = data.children;
var newsGrid = document.getElementById('js-news__grid');

for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
   articles[i].classList.add('loading');
   newsGrid.appendChild(articles[i]);
};
```

The `data` variable is a fragment of a successful XHR.  When I run the loop, it only appends the first child and the loop ends, and when running `console.log(articles);` before the loop, it shows 2 HTML elements (like it should) but only has a length of 1.  If I remove the loop and run `console.log(articles);` it shows the 2 HTML elements like before, BUT it now has a length of 2.

I've left out my XHR code for the sake of simplicity and due to the fact that the HTMLCollection that is produced from data.children looks correct.  Here are the log messages:

```
[article.news__item, article.news__item]
0: article.news__item
1: article.news__item
length: 2
__proto__: HTMLCollection

[article.news__item, article.news__item]
0: article.news__item
length: 1
__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) is a live collection, which will get updated as you move each child out of the container.

In your case, there are 2 children for `data` so `articles.length` is 2 when the loop is started, but after the first iteration you have relocated the first child which means the `articles` object is now contains only 1 element and `i` is 2 now the loop condition `i < articles.length` fails.

So one easy solution is to use a reverse loop

```
var articles = data.children;
var newsGrid = document.getElementById('js-news__grid');

for (var i = articles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    articles[i].classList.add('loading');
    newsGrid.appendChild(articles[i]);
};
```

Another solution will be is to convert `articles` to a normal array

```
var articles = [].slice.call(data.children);
```

---

Another approach as suggested by [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) is

```
var articles = data.children;
var newsGrid = document.getElementById('js-news__grid');

while (articles.length) {
    articles[0].classList.add('loading');
    newsGrid.appendChild(articles[0]);
};
```

Comment: Or use a while loop: `while (articles.length) newsGrid.appendChild(articles[0]);`. Using *slice* to create an array from the collection will fail in IE8 and lower, it doesn't allow passing host objects to built–in methods as *this*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG yes... thanks... updated `while` option also in the answer