# DocumentFragment is losing part of my content

Tags: javascript, html, documentfragment

So I'm basicaly just trying move element from one node to an other.
I create a fragment and then append to it my children elements.

```js
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
let sortedElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.product')].sort((a,b) => b.dataset.blockSize - a.dataset.blockSize ); //Select elements
sortedElements.forEach((e) => {
    console.log(e) //My 4 children displayed
    fragment.appendChild(e)
});
console.log(fragment.children); //Only Two children in it

fragment.childNodes.forEach((el) => {
    document.querySelector("#appendThere").appendChild(el);
})
```

```html
<div class="product" data-object-size="4">Product 1</div>
<div class="product" data-object-size="2">Product 2</div>
<div class="product" data-object-size="1">Product 3</div>
<div class="product" data-object-size="1">Product 4</div>

<div id="appendThere"></div>
```

Am I missunderstanding how does fragments works ?

It's strangely working on snippet... 
Even partialy working on my computer But its getting stranger.

[image]

[image]

I think there is a change between the moment I print my variable and I explore it.

Comment: [I can't reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/yuledaquja/1/edit?html,js,console) - can you add something that reproduces the issue? As a pure guess, are some of the items with class "product" children of other elements with class "product"?

Comment: @benvc I've tried to edit it but as you said it's indeed strange

Comment: @benvc Well I've changed it it has nothing to do with the HTML most probably it's due to the way the memory of Fragment is being used.

Comment: @VLAZ There you have a working Snippet with my bug

Comment: @Baldráni ok, weird - the console log does show 4 but when appended, you only get every other item

Comment: look at this SO answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31332027/10921798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating `fragment.childNodes` while iterating over it, which is causing the unexpected behavior. You just need to append `fragment` rather than appending each of it's children.

For example (fixed the element data attributes to correspond to the sort js in your example):

```js
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const sorted = [...document.querySelectorAll('.product')].sort((a,b) => {
  return b.dataset.blockSize - a.dataset.blockSize;
});

sorted.forEach((elem) => {
  fragment.appendChild(elem);
});

document.querySelector('#destination').appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<div class="product" data-block-size="3">Product 2</div>
<div class="product" data-block-size="1">Product 3</div>
<div class="product" data-block-size="4">Product 1</div>
<div class="product" data-block-size="1">Product 4</div>
<div id="destination"></div>
```

Or, without using a document fragment (may not be a big performance difference if you are working with a limited number of elements).

```js
const destination = document.querySelector('#destination');
const sorted = [...document.querySelectorAll('.product')].sort((a,b) => {
  return b.dataset.blockSize - a.dataset.blockSize;
});

sorted.forEach((elem) => {
  destination.appendChild(elem);
});
```

```html
<div class="product" data-block-size="3">Product 2</div>
<div class="product" data-block-size="1">Product 3</div>
<div class="product" data-block-size="4">Product 1</div>
<div class="product" data-block-size="1">Product 4</div>
<div id="destination"></div>
```

Comment: Sadely can't do that but reduce or a process equivalent would be working! Thanks for the link

Comment: @Baldráni - if you can't append the document fragment, then you probably don't need to use one at all. Why not just append the elements directly to the destination and skip the fragment step altogether? Added a second example to the answer to illustrate.

Comment: Because I do not append the element to the same elements :)

Comment: @Baldráni - in that case, you definitely don't need to use a document fragment unless you are appending groups of elements, which you could use multiple document fragments to accomplish.